# Asking for first class meal while having economy class ticket

Tags: bookings, in-flight-services

I'm a frequent flyer on international flights. Basically, the economy class ticket is bought by the company and of course includes an economy class meal. I wonder if after booking the ticket there is a procedure for asking a first class meal or if I can ask for an upgrade of my meal while I'm on board the airplane. I'm fine with topping up the price difference(if there is such).

Comment: Generally this isn't possible (especially once you're on the plane), but I know certain airlines (e.g. KLM) allow you to purchase upgraded meals (though not necessarily the first-class equivalent).

Comment: They have to load the meals before take-off. They can't send out for another.

Comment: Interesting question. What happens if you just ask them outright at service time?  Something like "Excuse me, may I have a 1st class meal today?"

Comment: @GayotFow If you fly on BA, you might not even get a first class meal in first, let alone in economy ...

Comment: @Calchas good, but I'm minded to try. meanwhile +1 for your answer below

Comment: @WeatherVane the times I've been in business or first class, it seemed that there was more than enough food to go around.  They were serving the main dishes from a serving dish to the passengers' plates rather than passing out prepackaged meals with fixed portion sizes.  They don't seem to cut it as close with the higher classes as they do with economy.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is no, although some airlines will allow you to purchase a special economy meal.

Airlines do not allow their premium class offerings to be split up. You either purchase the whole package or you get none of it. The meal is probably less than 15 USD per person at cost, plus a similar amount per bottle of wine at bulk discount prices, but there's no way the airline will reveal that. Nor are they going to discourage people from buying first class by suggesting the experience can be replicated in separate, cheap pieces.

In any event, a first class meal is not heated on a pre-prepared tray like the economy meals are. Each course is individually prepared in the galley and then hand-delivered to the table. I don't even see how a typical first class meal would fit on an economy seat tray. The meal presentation is a big part of it: you will need at least one cabin crew member for every ten or so passengers, because it is quite labour-intensive. You can't replicate that in the middle of an economy cabin, you don't have the space in the galley and you don't have spare members of the cabin crew to do it.

---

To be honest, you are not missing much. I would suggest enjoying a good meal in an airport restaurant and skipping the on-board service. You will probably eat better than the first class passengers.

Comment: Does anybody knows which airlines are allowing on an economy class passenger to purchase upgraded meals ?

Comment: @Kostas [KLM does](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/on_board/dining_on_board/alacarte_menu.htm).

Comment: "You will probably eat better than the first class passengers" is probably true for any North American airline, but I have enjoyed the food when I've managed to fly first class on several Asian carriers (I'm particularly fond of Singapore Airlines).

Comment: KLM's meals are not really "upgraded", rather they are simply "you can choose your own menu" program.  The offerings sound fancier, but don't really taste better (based on trying it once).

Comment: I've been offered the business class salad when the airline could not honour my request for vegetarian, due to an error on my side (Korean Air).

Comment: Aerlingus transatlantic flight offered me the chance to 'upgrade' my meal for about $25. I declined.

Comment: @Kostas Air France does too, and claims that the upgraded meals are identical to those served in business (not first). I actually did buy an upgraded meal on my last long-haul AF flight (CDG to KIX), and thought it was worth the 12 EUR.

Comment: Thanking everybody for guidance. AF site is stating about "A LA CARTE" menus, which are looking nice. Does somebody have any experiences with such meals ?

Comment: I bought an upgraded meal for my partner flying on Air France once. He said it was okay, but not worth the money I paid.

Comment: @Dennis I've flown once on Singapore, in economy, from Frankfurt to New York, in 2003.  There were three meals instead of the usual two, and the food was well above average for an economy meal.  I can only imagine that the higher-class meals are even better.

Comment: I would suggest eating in a restaurant **before** heading to the airport. Here in Lisbon, prices are inflated as much as 3-10x in the airport.